# Inserting an entity which contains a reference to another entity in MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am quite new to NoSQL databases, as I always worked with SQL. I have a problem on how to insert entities which contain a reference to a separate document objects. According to best pracites etc.
Here's the code (with unnecessary bits stripped out)

**Entities for MongoDB** (repository can contain many projects, however it's the project entities that will be queried, added, updated and removed most often, hence no reference to collection of projects in repository, but the other way round)

```
//entities are not *that* small, each contains several primitive properties
public class Repository 
{
    [BsonId, BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Project 
{
    [BsonId, BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObjectId RepositoryId { get; set; }
}
```

There is an API endpoint which accepts a DTO which looks like that:

```
//DTOs are not *that* small, each contains several primitive properties
public class ProjectDto 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Repository Repository { get; set; }

}
public class Repository
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The controller accepts this ProjectDTO and should insert that to the DB, **having 3 goals in mind**:

1. If the Repository specified in the ProjectDTO does not exist (based by the name), it needs to be added
2. If the Repository already exists, then the new project needs to be added and the Repository ID should point to the existing Repository
3. If the Project already exist it should simply be updated. The repository would have been properly assigned already

The DB access in my app happens in a service class, as per this documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Now, question #1:

**Is it a fine pattern to pass the DTO to the Service class, and let it then Map it to entities and perform inserts etc.? Don't think so, but maybe:)**

Regardless, I could achieve the goals by:

1. Finding the repository based on name (DB call #1)
2. Adding it if it did not exist (DB call #2)
3. Returning the ID of the existing repository
4. Finding the existing project (get project by name where ID of repository matches) (DB call #3/4)
5. Updating if it did exist (DB call #4/5)
6. Mapping the DTO to a Project entity and assigning the RepositoryId to the ID of existing repository
7. Inserting the new project to projects collection (DB call #4/5)

Question #2:

**Is that approach fine?**

Kind regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the mongo documentation for updates in [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/). Check the IsUpsert option which I think can achieve what you want:

> **Upsert Option**
>
> If UpdateOne, UpdateMany, or ReplaceOne includes an
> UpdateOptions argument instance with the IsUpsert option set to true
> and no documents match the specified filter, then the operation
> creates a new document and inserts it. If there are matching
> documents, then the operation modifies or replaces the matching
> document or documents.

But also review the [Model One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) article . You can change how you store your data, having repositories and embedded in each repository document its projects.